# WPF ListView - Event when the control is ready for iterating over rendered items?

Tags: wpf, listview, .net-4.0, itemcontainergenerator

I have a WPF ListView control with ItemsSource set to a collection of item ViewModel class instances. ListView has ItemTemplate with custom control hierarchy.

I need to do certain things to those controls generated via ItemTemplate when the ListView is actually shown (if not already visible) and all of it's items are layed out (i.e. when it's safe to use `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem`).

If I subscribe to `ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged`, when the status changes to `GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated` there are still no items in the generator (?!? btw.). How can I be notifed when the ListView is ready for iterating over the *actual controls* that are bound to items, even when ItemsSource is changed at runtime on an existing control?

Now, I know I can subcribe to events of the *actual control* in the template, but I need to know when *all* of the item controls are created, doing stuf in the item's viewmodel doesn't help me since I need to do UI-related stuff, like animations, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, there isn't such an event. You may be able to use the [LayoutUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated.aspx) event, but that is fired more than once as the ListView is updated.

Keep in mind also, that if virtualization is enabled, then not all the containers will be created at once.

Your best bet would be to use an attached behavior (see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx) and [here](http://eladm.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/attached-behavior/)) for the ListViewItem, which you can apply using an implicit Style.

For example, if you created a class called MyBehavior with a boolean attached property named MyProperty with a default value of false, then the Style would be something like:

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="local:MyBehavior.MyProperty" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

When your property is set to true, you know the ListViewItem has been created and should be ready to render. If not, you can attach to the Loaded event to know when to do your work.

Comment: Nice trick with the attached behavior but it won't help me, since it would fire per-listitem, besides, I think I can already achieve that with datatemplate.control.loaded event. I need the event when *all* of the items are loaded and layed out, since my animation effects depend on the number of items and their order. I could track each item's `loaded` and decrease some counter until it reaches zero, but that would be last resort.